# Debounce network requests

Tags: javascript

I have a list of items and the order of the items can be re-sorted by the user. When the list order is updated, a `onSortEnd` function fires immediately. It sends the new order to my server to update the ordering. I have the network request working, however I'm trying to implement a debounce to limit the amount of times the order is sent to my server. For example, if a user changes the order 3 times in the span of 10 seconds, I really only need to send the last order, rather than all 3. I have the request working just fine, but for some reason my request is firing as soon as the list is re-ordered, rather than debouncing and I'm not quite sure why.

**debounce function:**

```
const debounce = (fn, delay) => {
  let timer = null;
  return () => {
    const context = this;
    const args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }, delay);
  };
};
```

**invoking debounce (class method in my React component that triggers when a list has been sorted):**

```
onSortEnd = () => {
  // this.props.updateItems makes the network request and works just fine...
  debounce(this.props.updateItems(updatedList), 3000, false);
};
```

I prefer doing this in vanilla Javascript. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have a similar question (but in typescript) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859667/debouncing-network-request-in-reactjs

Answer (score 0):

Try RxJS#debounce, See [RxJS-debounce](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/debounce.md)